# How to write while loop inside while in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to make a small practice app, where user is asked their name, if its "joni" then there is a reply with YES or EXIT question. if User types YES it loops to asking question again, if user types EXIT it stops.

My problem is, how to make loop of asking YES or EXIT question if the user types different thing?

for example user types NO, so it will be asked again PLEASE TYPE YES or EXIT. But in my app it just exits if user types different thing than YES.

```html
string? myValue;

do
{
    Console.Write("Hey whats ur name?: ");
    string? myName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (myName == "joni")
    {
        Console.Write("Hey joni! Do you want to conitnue? YES or EXIT: ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Hey student! Do you want to conitnue? YES or EXIT: ");
    }

    myValue = Console.ReadLine();

} while (myValue.ToLower() == "yes");

if (myValue.ToLower() == "exit")
{
    Console.WriteLine("THANKS FOR USING MY APP!");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You need to use an ```equals()``` method rather than ```==```.

```myValue.ToLower().Equals("yes")```

Comment: *But in my app it just exits if user types different thing than YES* Have you actually attached a debugger and stepped though the code?

Comment: @JakeBringham No you don't. `myValue.ToLower()` returns a string, and the `==` operator is defined on `string`.

Comment: You should test for exit inside the loop, not outside the loop. Try using the debugger and learn how to do that. It is very helpful to discover logic errors. Search google for Visual Studio C# debug code or something like that and you will find tutorials on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
myValue = Console.ReadLine();
while (myValue.ToLower() is not "yes" and not "exit")
{
    Console.WriteLine("PLEASE TYPE YES or EXIT");
    myValue = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it needed some corrections, didnt work with "is not" I needed to write like this  while ((myValue.ToLower() != "yes") && (myValue.ToLower() != "exit")) than it worked!

Comment: `is not "yes" or "exit"`isn't C#. I don't get why someone would upvote it.

Comment: @Lado Yes, you would need to do that if you're not using C#9+

Comment: @PalleDue This uses [logical patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) that were introduced in C#9. Although my original logic was incorrect :).

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: OK, I didn't know. You always learn something new on stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I developed the `menu()` function to solve this problem. If the accepted entries are incorrect, the program prompts the user to enter a new menu value.

```cs
public static bool menu()
{
    string? myValue;

    do{
        Console.WriteLine("Your Chooice: ");
        myValue = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (!(myValue.ToLower().Equals("yes") || myValue.ToLower().Equals("exit")));

    if (myValue.ToLower() == "yes")
        return true;
    
    return false;
}
```

The `menu()` method can be used as follows:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do{
        Console.Write("Hey whats ur name?: ");
        string? myName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", myName);
    } while (menu());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```